# Disable overview of all applications when opening application launcher

Tags: gnome-shell, activities-overview

When pressing the SUPER button in Ubuntu, the gnome application launcher opens AND all open windows are shown. I find the showing of all open windows sometimes a bit too much and overwhelming. Sometimes I just want to quickly open a new application by typing in the application launcher search bar.

Is it possible to only have the gnome application launcher search box, without showing the overview of all open applications?

Comment: Are sure it's Unity? What's your Ubuntu version?

Comment: You are right... It's Ubuntu 18.04, so it is the gnome application launcher, right?

Comment: I also find "too much" is happening if one just wants to launch an application. That is why I use an application launcher, Albert. It likely could be achieved with an extension, but afaik none that does this currently exists. You could rebind the Super key to the Application overview to have a - still overwhelming - effect focussed on launching an application.

Comment: Not really an answer, but what about super+A instead of just super?

Comment: With super+A I still zoom out on second monitor...

Comment: @vanadium Switching to a 3rd party app launcher was what I am trying to avoid. But probably there is no other choice.

Comment: You did not make reference to "second monitor" in your question. So your idea is probably more that launching the application search would *not at all* go into overview mode. I was thinking you just wanted the application windows not shown when venturing in the overview. Of course, instead of a 3rd party app launcher, you could also consider an extension such as the Arc menu, which, on Super, launches a traditional application menu ready to search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround for searching applications, you can use the key combo **Super+A**. This will allow you to search without displaying the overview of all the open windows. If you also need to  search files and documents, then you can install [Synapse](https://itsubuntu.com/install-synaptic-package-manager-ubuntu/).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your direct request, have the search box appear on your desktop without switching to the overview, will not be possible at this time without editing source code. An extension that does that is not currently existing.

To quickly launch an application without leaving your current desktop view, you may consider some alternative ways.

1) Use an alternative keyboard launcher such as [Albert](https://albertlauncher.github.io/), [ULauncher](https://ulauncher.io/) or [Synapse](https://launchpad.net/synapse-project).

2) Use a Gnome Shell extension that provides a searchable application menu that pops out of your top bar, such as [Arc Menu](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1228/arc-menu/) or [Gno-menu](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/608/gnomenu/).